# Laravel varible sessione how to use?

Tags: laravel

I am a neophyte of Laravel,
I would like to understand how to retrieve the name of the user who logged in and then show it on my homepage using session variables,
how could I do?

Comment: Search on Laravel Docs about: session and auth. Give a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Auth` facade anywhere you want and retrieve authenticated data from it like `Auth::user()` and if you want specific data you can do this `Auth::user()->name`

And this is the [Laravel reference of Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways: `\Auth::user()` or `auth()->user()`
These ways will return the instance of user